# determining which item of a list was clicked- javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, windows, list, click

I have a winJS list which is full of images. When a user clicks on an image, they are being sent to a second page. Is there any way of being able to determine which image the user clicked on page 1 (each image, when clicked, goes to the same page 2 but with a custom div). Here is my list declared and then I am push items to it:

```
var names_Array = [];

var names_List = new WinJS.Binding.List(names_Array);

var idPL;
names_List.push({ name: "man 1", image: "image/man1.png", ClientID: "1111" });

names_List.push({ name: "man 2 ", image: "image/man2.png", ClientID: "2222" }); 



idPL = document.getElementById("names_List");
                 idPL.addEventListener("iteminvoked", onclickItem);


function onclickItem(e) {
      console.log("Item clicked");
}
```

A the minute I am populating the div based on which item was last pushed to the list, but I need this to be more flexible and be able to select the first item (even after a second one has been added)
EDIT: I AM NOW GETTING AN ERROR 'Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference'. I THOUGHT I had defined it in my code above

Answer (score 1):

To get the detail of which item is clicked in winjs listview we can use itemInvoke event of the Winjs listview.

```
<div id="itemsList" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display:none;">

       <div data-win-bind="className: type">
             <img src="#" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" 
                 data-win-bind="alt: title; src: picture" />

           <div>
            <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: title" style="width:100px; height:20px;"></h4>
           </div>
           <div>
               <img  id="like"src="images/like.png" class="win-interactive"  data-win-bind="alt:title; onclick: LikeClick;" />
               </div>
       </div>

    </div>

 <div id="UserListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" style="border-top: 5px solid #000; min-width:500px;" 
           data-win-options="{
                               selectionMode:'multi',
                               itemTemplate:select('#itemsList'),
                               layout:{    
                               type:WinJS.UI.GridLayout}}"
         > 

    </div>
```

then in the js

UserListView.addEventListener("iteminvoked", ItemInvoke);
 function ItemInvoke(evt) {

```
    var name=evt.detail.itemPromise._value.data.title;
    var picturePath=evt.detail.itemPromise._value.data.picture;
}
```

Here in this listview we are only displaying the image and title of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Either assign an [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) globally and check which was clicked and do something, or assign an [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) per item and do whatever you require.

UPDATE: I am unable to demonstrate using WinJS, but this example should suffice.

HTML

```
<ul id="names_List"></ul>
```

Javascript

```
var names_Array = [],
    idPL = document.getElementById("names_List");

names_Array.push({
    name: "man 1",
    image: "image/man1.png",
    ClientID: "1111"
});

names_Array.push({
    name: "man 2 ",
    image: "image/man2.png",
    ClientID: "2222"
});

names_Array.forEach(function (item) {
    var li = document.createElement("li"),
        img = document.createElement("img");

    img.name = item.name;
    img.src = item.img;

    li.appendChild(img);
    idPL.appendChild(li);
});

function onclickItem(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === "IMG") {
        console.log("Item clicked", e.target.name);
    }
}

idPL.addEventListener("click", onclickItem, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/YUYyR/)

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat your image urls to include:

1. A hash: `image.html#man1.png`
2. A query string: `image.html?image=man1.png`

And then use those to extract information from the URL using JavaScript for when the 2nd page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way you can do this is by declaring a namespace with the value of the image inside an eventlistener for selectionchanged, like this:

```
            listview.addEventListener("selectionchanged", function (item) {
            listview.selection.getItems().done(function (items) {
            WinJS.Namespace.define("imageInformation", {
                        seletedImage: items[0].data.image,
                    });
            }, false);
```

After the namespace is declared, you can access it on the other page:

```
var path = imageInformation.selectedImage;
```